# Python: Popen stdout=PIPE can't read progress bar output

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, stdout

I'm trying to route the progress bar from a console application over a UDP socket to remotely show the status of completion of a task. For some odd reason all data from output from subprocess stdout.PIPE could be read except the progress bar which appeared blank if I tried to write to a file or transmit over a UDP socket. I suspect the progress bar isn't being channeled to stdout.PIPE at all due to not ending with \n since if I remove the print statement for stdout.PIPE the progress bar still prints in the console. I've tried to reproduce the problem with tqdm library:

**sample_process.py**

```
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    
for i in tqdm(range(10)):
    sleep(0.5)
```

**client.py**

```
import socket
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CalledProcessError

serverAddressPort   = ("127.0.0.1", 20001)
bufferSize          = 1024

UDPClientSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
cmd = ['python', 'sample_process.py']

with Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=0, universal_newlines=True) as p:
    for line in p.stdout:
        print(line, end='')
        UDPClientSocket.sendto(line.encode(), serverAddressPort)

if p.returncode != 0:
    raise CalledProcessError(p.returncode, p.args)
```

**server.py**

```
import socket

UDPServerSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPServerSocket.bind(("127.0.0.1", 20001))
while(True):
    bytesAddressPair = UDPServerSocket.recvfrom(1024)
    message = bytesAddressPair[0]
    print(message.decode())
```

If I do print(p.stdout.read()), then I don't get any output till end out process. Is there anyway to read the progress bar in real-time? I'm using Python 3.9.13 on Windows 11.

Comment: For starters, are you sure that tqdm writes the progress bar to stdout? It would make a lot of sense to write it to stderr.

Comment: @TurePålsson and Itqan Ullah: indeed, as documented (https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/#__init__), the progress bar is written to stderr by default. The code of sample_process.py can be fixed with the following for loop head: `for i in tqdm(range(10), file=sys.stdout):`. I just tried with Python 3.10 on Windows

Comment: Oh yes, thanks! Changing "for line in p.stdout" to "for line in p.stderr" and adding an additional stderr=PIPE does seem to work perfectly for capturing progress bar, but now I can't get output stderr and stdout at the same time. The tqdm example was a recreation of the problem. The original problem was with a different CLI based program so changing the code in tqdm script won't solve it in my case. I'm able to capture the progress bar now on the original program though. Thanks @TurePålsson and simon.

Comment: Changed "with Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=0, universal_newlines=True) as p:" to "with Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:" Works perfectly now as expected! Solved.

Comment: @ItqanUllah Glad to hear that! You might want to do two things now: (1) Change the title of your question (as, in hindsight, it seems a bit misleading) and (2) add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Done. Will accept once two day limit of stackoverflow expires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems my speculation was wrong, the progress bar output was being channeled to std.err which is why it was not being captured. Changing the code in **client.py** to following fixes the problem:

```
import socket
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CalledProcessError, STDOUT

serverAddressPort   = ("127.0.0.1", 20001)
bufferSize          = 1024

UDPClientSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
cmd = ['python', 'sample_process.py']

with Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
        for line in p.stdout:
            print(line, end='')
            UDPClientSocket.sendto(line.encode(), serverAddressPort)
        

if p.returncode != 0:
    raise CalledProcessError(p.returncode, p.args)
```

Credits to @TurePålsson and @simon for rightfully pointing that out in the comments.